# How can I ensure that my CoffeeScripts are only loaded on the pages that they need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

One of the things that I don't understand about the Asset Pipeline in Rails 3.2 is that I have seen several references to the application.js file that contain the following line:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Is it true that this load all of my javascripts on every single page? Because really, I don't want a "products" CoffeeScript to load to the browser when a user is on a "categories" page (for example), since none of that code will be used.

If the behavior I have stated above is an accurate description of how `require_tree` works in the Asset Pipeline, is there a way to ensure that only the CoffeeScripts that are required for a particular view are loaded instead of all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true that this load all of my javascripts on every single page?

Yes, this is what it does. Rails will compile your CoffeeScripts into JavaScripts, and then  concatenate and minify (in production) them into one file. That file will be included in every page.

> Because really, I don't want a "products" CoffeeScript to load to the browser when a user is on a "categories" page...

Yes, you do. That's the whole point. This one bundled JavaScript file loads on *every page*. This way, the browser downloads the entire site's JavaScript once as one file, during the first request, and uses a cached copy on every other page.

> ... since none of that code will be used

Including the extra code on every page has literally no cost if it's not executed and loaded from the cache. Meanwhile it provides a huge savings since you're minimizing the number of requests for external JavaScript, which means your scripts can run immediately and your DOM-ready event fires that much sooner.

It's up to you to make sure this is safe, and that your code targets only the parts of the site that it's supposed to affect. Typically you would do this by selecting specific elements by ID and making sure your IDs aren't shared between pages, and that you aren't applying classes with special meaning to elements that shouldn't have them.

> Is there a way to ensure that only the CoffeeScripts that are required for a particular view are loaded instead of all of them?

No, not without creating separate manifest files for each page which defeats one of the major purposes of using the Asset Pipeline. Don't do this. It's correct, desired and intentional that your entire minified JavaScript bundle file be included on every page.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. This way it only needs to load once. And  it also will help to enforce naming practices of HTML elements on different views, which I was lax on and which was causing me errors. Thanks!